# MWE for page breaking problems

Tags: discussion, mwe

I have a large computer-generated document in which page breaks aren't appearing where I want them, despite liberal use of `\pagebreak` and `nopagebreak`.  It's a real headache as even if I cut out two or three pages worth of material, it's going to be too long for a reasonable MWE. Does anyone have any clever ideas about how I might be able to condense material enough to construct a sensible question?

Edit: I finally figured out something that wasn't too bad... I'd still be interested in solutions to this, though..

Comment: you might try reducing the page length to accommodate only ten lines or fewer.  that would still make for a largish example, but perhaps manageable.

Comment: Fill the irrelevant parts via `blindtext`,`lipsum`, or `kantlipsum` packages and only include the problematic part near the pagebreak.

Comment: The main problem is that the 'irrelevant' parts are complex diagrams generated by a bucketload of LaTeX code. If I replace with blindtext, etc., all the page breaks shift.

Comment: Measure them and put in `\rule`s.

Comment: That sounds very promising. I'll go away and read up about measuring things.